# Exhaust leak despite tightening the flange all the way

Tags: exhaust, leak

I replaced the catalytic converter on my 93 Miata with a test pipe. The issue is there is an exhaust leak that I can't seem to fix. I tightened the flange all the way around and it still leaks.

It only leaks from one side and at first it leaked from below the pipe but after flipping the gasket and re-tightening it now leaks from above. I tried to buy a new gasket and had the same issue. I spent more than an hour around that flange and tightened it as best as I could but it still leaked

Is it safe to use RTV to get rid of the leak? Otherwise how can I fix this problem?

Update: I used 2 gaskets and the leak improved but it was still there. One thing that came to mind is I didnt clean the mating surface of the pipe, is that something that should be done to exhaust flanges as it never occured to me?

If so how is it done properly?

Comment: RTV isn't going to cut it. Is this on the end with the donut or the one that goes to the midpipe? A better solution than RTV - which will work until it gets cooked by the heat of the exhaust - would be a thicker gasket. The most likely issue is that the flange on your test pipe isn't flat, so it won't mate with the gasket + exhaust manifold correctly.

Comment: The gasket that came with the pipe is pretty thick, thicker than the one I bought from the store. Is it safe to double gasket? could that solve it? and the leak is not from the header side but the one facing the muffler

Comment: I have had good luck sealing this type of leak with Muffler Putty. It is like a premixed refractory cement.  I've only used the Loctite brand which comes in a can. Apply a liberal amount to both sides of the gasket. Tighten the flange to squeeze out the excess. I have had the best luck letting it dry overnight so the exhaust pressure doesn't blow it out.

Comment: Are the flanges bent or mis-aligned?

Comment: @SolarMike No it seems perfect, I got it from racing beat

Comment: And what about the other one?

Comment: They both line up perfectly with no issues

Comment: If they line up perfectly, and the gasket is good, there should be no leak. Either the gasket itself is bad, and is the source of the leak, or the flanges aren't flat, or the leak is from elsewhere. It's a pretty simple system: two flat surfaces with a squeezable thing between them make a good seal.

Comment: @DavidLively I guess that means that the flange isn't flat and that's where the issue lies, is this a manufacture problem or what could it be? and how do I solve it?

Comment: It *could* be a manufacturing issue. These things are normally cast, which should prevent that kind of thing (other than physical damage from, say, poor handling during shipping). Have you talked to Racing Beat about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to my own incompetency, @David Lively made it clear for me. I was not aware that the old catalytic converter gasket was baked on the mid pipe. Just running my hands on it made it so obvious.

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
It's new.  Look into how I fixed my leaks.   C Flange Bracket